# Can food swallowed when a person is upside down reach the stomach?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, food, human-physiology

If a person positions him/herself upside down and swallows food, will it reach the stomach against gravity? If so how?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallowing#Pharyngeal_phase, phase 11. So... yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eminent @JanDvorak has basically provided the full answer, but yes, it is possible.  You can easily try this yourself, just lean off a bed and swallow something (small) and see what happens.  [Peristalsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristalsis) in the esophagus is responsible for moving food down into the stomach.  The big proof of this is that astronauts can [eat when in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_food), when weightless.  Their food is moved into the stomach just fine.

It's easier to do it upright (`peristalsis + gravity`) as opposed to upside down (`peristalsis - gravity`) but definitely quite possible.

Comment: It is _not_ a good idea to experiment with this just like that. A part of food can enter your larynx and bronchi and eventually lead to aspiration pneumonia.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. As I myself have experienced it.I was doing a headstand when I tried it.It does take a lot of time but does reach the stomach.